# Image Slider not working only on Magento Frontend Homepage

Tags: image, magento, slider, frontend

I am trying to solve an issue that I do not even know when started. My general frontend template has a image slides on the right column. All internal pages of my website show the image slider without problems, however the homepage hides the slides. If you use the chrome inspection, all the elements are there, but not visible. Any idea of how to solve this?

Homepage: http://lojaanalitica.com.br/

Example of internal page: http://lojaanalitica.com.br/combos.html

Comment: On right side slider is working on home page..